# Show the size of the image in siview

Tags: python

I am currently printing the size of the image in terminal. How can I get the size below these two images separately.

```
print('size of original image: ', int(os.stat(f).st_size / 1024), 'kB')
            print('size of compressed image:', int(os.stat('compressed_' + f).st_size / 1024), 'kB')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got the answer myself. To print the integer value from a variable below the plots.

```
     org = int(os.stat(f).st_size / 1024)
                    ax1.set_xlabel('The size is %d' % org)

             comp = int(os.stat('compressed_' + f).st_size / 1024)
                ax2.set_xlabel('The size is %d' % comp)
```